# How to create a function that will add a a value to array in object

Tags: mongodb-query

I want to create a function that will add a grade to specific student and subject

This is how my document looks

```
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b454b545b4545b"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "last_name" : "Bob",
    "nr_album" : "222",
    "grades" ; {
         "IT" : [
               3,
               3,
               5,
               4
              ]
}
```

This is what I came up with

```
function addGrade(
nr_album,grades,value
) {
db.studenci.update (
{nr_album: nr_album},
{ $push: { [grades]: value}});
}

addGrade("222","grades.IT",100)
```

It`s working properly, but what I want to achieve is to except "grades.IT" pass only "IT" in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) in ES2015.

Pass Arguments like that

```
addGrade("222","IT",100)
```

Get parameters **"IT"** and make it dynamically required string

```
function addGrade(nr_album, grades, value) {
  const string = `grades.{$grades}`
  db.studenci.update({
    nr_album: nr_album
  }, {
    $push: { [string]: value }
  });
}
```